# iPhone doesn't installed ipa build from TestFlight

Tags: download, iphone-5, testflight

I have an `ipa` file on `TestFlight` even though the device have permission after downloading 80% of the App, it gives an error. Please see the pic.

[image]

Comment: I have resolved this issue by adding Device Capabilities as an armv7 in App Plist.